# An Error in Manual for Package pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

One can see in page 353 "Manual for Package pgfplots Version 1.16" the below code.
I run it, however, I have an error

> ```
> ! Dimension too large.
> <recently read> \pgf@xx 
>  l.28 \end{loglogaxis}
> ```

When `\draw` command is Inactive, it worked!
Dear friends, where is the problem?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{‎amsmath}‎
‎‎\usepackage{tikz}‎‎
\usepackage{pgfplots}‎
‎
‎\usepackage{graphicx}‎‎
‎
%\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
‎%‎\begin{figure}
‎%‎\pgfplotsset{compat=1.‎16‎}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}‎‎[title=Convergence Plot, xlabel={Degrees of freedom}, ylabel={$L_2$ Error},legend entries={$d=2$,$d=3$}‎,‎grid=‎major‎,‎]‎‎
‎
‎‎\draw (1793,4.442e-05) ‎|-‎ (4097,1.207e-05) node [near start,left] {$‎‎\frac{dy}{dx} =‎ ‎-1.58‎$}‎;‎
‎‎\addplot coordinates {
(5, 8.312e-02)
(17, 2.547e-02)
(49, 7.407e-03)
(129, 2.102e-03)
(321, 5.874e-04)
(769, 1.623e-04)
(1793, 4.442e-05)
(4097, 1.207e-05)
(9217, 3.261e-06‎)‎
‎ }‎;‎
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%\caption{...}
‎%‎\end{figure}
\end{‎document}‎
```

Comment: If you include the `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}` command again, it works. Not sure why it does not otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work again

Comment: I noticed that there are a lot of `U+200E` symbols in your code which might be the root cause of your problem. Removing them and -- as Psirus already mentioned in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488713/an-error-in-manual-for-package-pgfplots#comment1234005_488713) -- uncommenting `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}` then works as expected.

Comment: If you do not immediately understand what @StefanPinnow is saying, paste your code e.g. [here](https://pteo.paranoiaworks.mobi/diacriticsremover/) to see where these characters are.

Comment: The issue why you need to set a not too old compatibility mode is the draw command. if you use `\draw (axis cs:1793,4.442e-05) |- (axis cs:4097,1.207e-05) node [near start,left] {$\frac{dy}{dx} = -1.58$};` instead it does work with `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} ` commented out. This is because from  pgfplots version 1.11 on `axis cs:` it is the default coordinate system but before it was not.

Comment: thank you  marmot, it work. you are really expert.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments